# Saving log to Azure Storage using Log4net from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, log4net

I have a MVC application which is a public site. I am using Log4net to store user's activity in Azure Storage.

I am storing contextual data in threadcontext and use this when message are logged into azure storage.

But for some reason it is taking the wrong values i.e some random values. I doubt that i am doing something wrong using this threadcontext.

Please find below my code snippet.

In my Mvc controller i am using

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CustomerID"] = username
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CreatedBy"] = createdbyusername
```

In custom Appender i am using as

```
var keys = log4net.ThreadContext.Properties.GetKeys();
CustomerID = keys.Contains("CustomerID") ? log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CustomerID"].ToString() : loggingEvent.Identity,
CreatedBy = keys.Contains("CreatedBy") ? log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CreatedBy"].ToString() : loggingEvent.Identity,
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this so that it takes the right value for each request?

My appender code:

```
protected void LogAudit(AuditEventType eventType, object additionalObject, string customerId = "")
{
    if (_logger != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerId))
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CustomerID"] = 
                customerId;

        AuthSSOProvider sso = new AuthSSOProvider();
        var helpDeskUser = sso.GetCookie(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("cookieKey"));
        if (helpDeskUser != null)
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["CreatedBy"] = 
                helpDeskUser;

        _logger.LogAudit(eventType, additionalObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the `Properties["CustomerID"]` or the `loggingEvent.Identity` that contains "some random values"?

Comment: If you just want to output the data you don't need a custom appender. Something like `(%property{CustomerID})` in the `conversionPattern` configuration of one of the standard appenders should be sufficient. Would that work for you?

Comment: It is the Properties["CustomerID"]. I am not output the data to a file instead storing it in Azure Storage.

Comment: There are appenders for Azure too (although maybe not _standard_) e.g. [log4net.Appender.Azure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure). Would you mind including the code for assigning values to the `username` and `createdbyusername` variables?